# Odoo many2one field related to one2many

Tags: odoo

I'm confused by something in the Odoo source code. On the `stock.picking` model, there is a `product_id` field. It's defined as a related field via `move_lines.product_id`.

`move_lines` is a one2many field. I don't understand how a many2one field can use a one2many field as its relation.

Here's a link to the source code I'm referring to:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/316ffc80147de076b28c6156ac679dd90da0935e/addons/stock/models/stock_picking.py#L288

You can see that `product_id` is defined as:

```
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', 'Product', related='move_lines.product_id')
```

And `move_lines` is defined as:

```
move_lines = fields.One2many('stock.move', 'picking_id', string="Stock Moves", copy=True)
```

What is the purpose of this definition? How is it even allowed?

If I look at the value of the `product_id` field for a picking, it returns the product for the first move line in the picking, not all of products.

However, if I search the picking tree view with a custom filter on the Product field, for example, `Product contains 'Product Name'`, the results seem to account for all products in the picking. If I search for any product in the picking the picking appears in the view, it's not just limited to the first product.

Can someone explain this behavior? There is even a note in the source code that the `product_id` field is specifically for searching, so I'm thinking there is some magic functionality I never knew about.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to the One2many field, it's related to the `move_lines` object (which is `stock.move` model), and takes from that model `product_id` field, which has a type of Many2one. So, everything is correct. [Here's](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/316ffc80147de076b28c6156ac679dd90da0935e/addons/stock/models/stock_move.py#L42) the code.

Comment: I see, so the fact that there are multiple stock.moves associated to the picking doesn't matter, since it references through to the product_id field, which is many2one? Is it true that it uses the first stock.move when actually returning a value for picking.product_id? And then when you search on picking.product_id, it knows to search the product_id for all of the stock.moves that are related to the picking?

Comment: Yeah, It takes the associated with the `stock.picking` the `stock.move` object and retrieves from it `product_id` field. It's not necessarily the first `stock.move` object from all of them, it takes the one that already associated with a `stock.picking`(via interface, for example). And yes, when you search on `picking.product_id`, you'll find the `product_id` from `stock_moves` model. Sorry for the delay with answering.